# Double check the size of a buffer

Tags: c, printf, overflow

I have a doubt about a potential buffer overflow in a library I developed, where there is the following API that can be called from external application. I've tried to find a possible solution but I didn't find yet the "right" one. The API is the following:

```
char* strftime_ISO8601(uint64_t ns, char* buf, size_t buflen) {
    if (buf) {
        //The standard format ISO 8601 is 20 bytes + 1 null
        char datetime[21];
        struct tm tm;
        struct timespec ts = //convert nanoseconds into timespec

        gmtime_r(&ts.tv_sec, &tm);
        strftime(datetime, sizeof(datetime), "+%FT%T", &tm);
        snprintf(buf, buflen, "%s.%.9ld", datetime, ts.tv_nsec);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

I need to provide code that is safe enough against "buffer overflow". For this reason I'm using the snprintf where the size of the destination buffer is given as parameter and the resulting string is NULL-terminated. 
I'm also using some static analysis tools like RATS to highlight potential vulnerability. In this case I have the following notice:

```
Double check that your buffer is as big as you specify. When using functions that accept a number n of bytes to copy, such as strncpy, be aware that if the destination buffer size = n it may not NULL-terminate the string.
```

on the snprintf

```
snprintf(buf, buflen, "%s.%.9ld", datetime, ts.tv_nsec);
```

Using the snprintf I'm sure that the string will be NULL-terminated, but how can I double check if the buffer given in input is really of size buflen?

I mean, if the user call the API with a bad size like e.g.

```
...
char bad[5]
strftime_ISO8601(x, bad, 1024);
....
```

or even worst using an uninitialized buffer like this:

```
...
char *bad;
strftime_ISO8601(x, bad, 1024);
...
```

A part from a potential segmentation fault, I don't see any particular vulnerability in the above API. But how can I verify if the buflen that the API receive as input is the right size?

Thank you all!

Comment: Minor: Why a `"+"` in `"+%FT%T"`?  Per [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it seems `+` only needed should the year value exist outside range 0-9999, in which case `char datetime[21];` is too small.

Comment: Minor: In experimenting with `"%F"`, a `+` or `-` was all ready added when needed.   Recommend dropping `+` and using a larger buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put simply - you can't...
There is no way to determine the "length" of a memory address you receive as pointer because there is no entity that can verify it in runtime. This is the reason you request the length in the first place!

The only solution in your case will be to allocate the memory yourself and return that to the user, transferring the responsibility for managing that memory to the user:

```
char* strftime_ISO8601(uint64_t ns) {
    //The standard format ISO 8601 is 20 bytes + 1 null
    char datetime[21];
    char *res = malloc(EXPECTED_SIZE)
    struct tm tm;
    struct timespec ts = //convert nanoseconds into timespec

    gmtime_r(&ts.tv_sec, &tm);
    strftime(datetime, sizeof(datetime), "+%FT%T", &tm);
    snprintf(res, EXPECTED_SIZE, "%s.%.9ld", datetime, ts.tv_nsec);

    return res;
}
```

This way, you are in control of the memory allocation and thus can prevent buffer overflows

Comment: Thnak you very much! I'll think to redisign this API for a future version of the library!